# curl_easy_opt throws EXE_BAD_Access or malloc pointer being freed was not allocated error

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, curl, memory-leaks

I have following run time error sometimes (not all the times)

> malloc: *** error for object 0x14: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

else

> EXE_BAD_ACCESS ( EXC_I386_GPFLT)

on the same line of code.

Please help me to solve this trouble.

I have following structure for curl based server connector. 
in **curlBasedServerConnector.cpp** see the place where **>>>ERROR POINTED HERE** line appear.

curlBasedServerConnector.hpp

```
 class curlBasedServerConnector  : public webServiceConnectorInterfaceA
{

private:
    CURLcode curlCode;
    CURL* curlHandle;        
    char* messagePtr;
    std::string message = "";        
    static std::atomic<int> totalNumOfCurlProcesses;
    static std::atomic<bool> isGlobalInitCalledAlready;
    static std::mutex curlGlobalInitKey;   
    static size_t writeContents_s(char *buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *up)
    {
        curlBasedServerConnector* pThis = static_cast<curlBasedServerConnector*>(up);
        return pThis->writeContents(buf, size, nmemb);
    }    
    // member version
    size_t writeContents(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
    {
        std::copy(buf, buf+(size*nmemb), std::back_inserter(message));
        return size*nmemb;
    }

public:

    bool executeOperation()override ;

    bool openConnection() override;

    bool setHttpHeader(const char* contentType, const char* charSet)override;

    bool setServerUrl(const char* url)override;

    void setRequest(const char* request)override;

    void closeConnection() override;
    std::string getResponseAsString()override;

    bool listenToNotification()override;

    void setTrace(bool trace);

    int getNumberofCurlProcessesInitialized();

    curlBasedServerConnector()
    {       
        curlGlobalInitKey.lock();
        {
            if(!isGlobalInitCalledAlready)
            {
                curlCode = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
                cout<<" Server Connector GLOBAL_INIT CALLED "<<endl;
                isGlobalInitCalledAlready = true;
                totalNumOfCurlProcesses++;
            }
            else
            {
                totalNumOfCurlProcesses++;            
            }            
        }
        curlGlobalInitKey.unlock();       
        openConnection();        
    }

    virtual ~curlBasedServerConnector(){

        curlGlobalInitKey.lock();        
        totalNumOfCurlProcesses--;        
        if(totalNumOfCurlProcesses == 0)
        {          
            curl_global_cleanup();      
        }        
        curlGlobalInitKey.unlock();      
    }  

};
```

curlBasedServerConnector.cpp

```
bool curlBasedServerConnector::openConnection(){
    bool successStatus = false;

    if(curlHandle )
    {
        cout<<"curl hanlde --"<<curlHandle<<endl;
        successStatus = true;            
    }
    else
    {
        curlHandle = curl_easy_init();

        if(curlHandle != NULL){

            successStatus = true;
        }
    }

    cout<<"openConnection() CURL CODE "<<curlCode<<endl;

    return successStatus;
}

void curlBasedServerConnector::closeConnection(){
     curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
}


bool curlBasedServerConnector::setServerUrl(const char *url){

    cout<<"curl handle at setting url "<<curlHandle<<endl;

  curlCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL,  url);  >>>ERROR POINTED HERE

    bool successStatus = false;

    if(curlCode == 0 | curlCode == CURLE_OK)
    {
        successStatus = true;
    }
    else if (curlCode == 27 | curlCode == CURLE_OUT_OF_MEMORY){

        exit(8);
    }        
    return successStatus;
}
```

webServiceConnectorInterfaceA.hpp

```
class webServiceConnectorInterfaceA
{

public:   

    virtual bool openConnection() = 0;
    virtual bool executeOperation()= 0; //
    virtual bool setHttpHeader(const char* contentType, const char* charSet) = 0;

    virtual bool setServerUrl(const char* url)=0;
    virtual void setRequest(const char* request)=0;
    virtual void closeConnection() = 0;
    virtual bool listenToNotification() = 0;

    virtual std::string getResponseAsString()=0;

    webServiceConnectorInterfaceA(){ };

     ~webServiceConnectorInterfaceA(){   };

};
```

I have accessor class which compose this class as following

```
class webServiceAccessor{
private:       
    const char* serverAddress = "http://localhost:2000";        
    std::shared_ptr<sharedQueue> gmsListenerQueue;
    std::shared_ptr<webServiceConnectorInterfaceA> webServiceConnectorInterface;

webServiceAccessor(){}
~webServiceAccessor(){}
```

}

Why it throws such error on the same line ? 
Who cause this error **curlBasedServerConnector class** or **class webServiceAccessor** ? 
How to solve this or debug this? 
I am using C++11 in Xcode IDE. 
Thanks

Trace when using malloc guard:

```
 GuardMalloc[TIFAR2-5307]: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.
GuardMalloc[TIFAR2-5307]:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.
GuardMalloc[TIFAR2-5307]:  - Applications using vector instructions (e.g., SSE) should work.
GuardMalloc[TIFAR2-5307]: version 108
TIFAR2(5307,0x100c31000) malloc: protecting edges
TIFAR2(5307,0x100c31000) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.5307.102c4c000.TIFAR2.M7TEpU.index
TIFAR2(5307,0x100c31000) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
TIFAR2(5307,0x100c31000) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
TIFAR2(5307,0x100c31000) malloc: process 5239 no longer exists, stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.5239.102c4c000.TIFAR2.YFARFr.index
WEB SERVICE CONNECTION STARTS HERE ......
 webServiceConnectorInterfaceA constructtor called 
.
.
.
```

Comment: `curlHandle` doesn't appear to be initialized. As far as I can tell, you are passing random garbage to `curl_easy_setopt`.

Comment: Thanks I figured this out. And changed to **curlHandle = NULL;**  It seems it works fine. Since the error come at random  point in time I am bit doubt my initialisation. Is initialising **curlHandle** to **NULL** valid?

Comment: It's valid in the sense that it makes `openConnection` actually call `curl_easy_init()`. I bet it wasn't doing that before.

Comment: Sorry Igor it worked before getting initialised to NULL. It throws run time errors on and off only.